# WinApi how to get the handle of the active element in a form

Tags: c++, windows, api, winapi

With the following code part, I can get the handle of the open file dialog box that is opened. That works fine.

```
HWND handleForWindow = FindWindow(NULL, "Open");
```

Now, I need to type the filepath + filename into the textbox area in the same dialog box. For this, I need to get the handle of the TextBox. I have been using Spy++ and it worked great so far. However, it doesn't get the handle of the TextBox. Spy++ says that the class is "Edit" and has no caption.

I tried the following and some other possibilities with the caption and the class name but no luck.

```
HWND hwndTextBox = FindWindowEx(handleForWindow, 0, "Edit", "Caption");
```

Actually the TextBox is a part of ComboBox. If I put there "ComboBox", it gets the handle nicely. But in that case if I send a text message to the box, it doesn't put any text there.

```
SendMessage(hwndTextBox, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"AnyText");
```

Since this doesn't work, I had an idea of getting the current active element in the window because the TextBox comes active all the time whenever it is opened. But I couldn't find any Api call for this. Could anyone help me about that?

Thanks.

Comment: EnumChildWindows or GetWindow with GWL_CHILD helps you.

Comment: Use a UI Automation library for this, especially if you are trying to commandeer another process.  Plenty of choices, C++ is not the weapon of choice.

Comment: Yes you are right but this is the last step that I need. If I can somehow fill the textbox, everything will be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a [`CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775839.aspx) message to a ComboBox to retrieve the `HWND` of its edit box.

If you are trying to interact with an [Open File dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960.aspx) from the Common Dialog library, you can send [`CDM_GETFOLDERPATH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CDM_GETFILEPATH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646847.aspx) messages to the dialog itself to get its current path and filename, and a [`CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646855.aspx) message to change the filename displayed in the dialog's `cmb13` or `edt1` field (see [Explorer-Style Control Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960.aspx#_win32_Explorer_Style_Control_Identifiers)).

Comment: That sounds very good but I couldn't get it working. So I need little bit of more help here.

SendMessage(handleForWindow, CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT, IDOK, (LPARAM)"Something");

This doesn't change anything.

Comment: This is poor comment. Do you have valid handle? Also from MSDN: dialog box must have been created with the OFN_EXPLORER flag.

Comment: Of course I am checking if it is a valid handle. However, I missed the part of OFN_EXPLORER flag. Thanks.